# why does cpo-=c cause perceptual "lag?"

Tags: search, set

I'm using a `CursorMoved` autocommand with `searchpos` to [do highlighting of special words](https://github.com/andymass/vim-matchup).  I've been using `set cpo-=c` to handle possible overlapping matches, and I restore it afterwards.  This `set` seems to be causing a lot of cursor lag when scrolling with `hjkl`.

However, I don't understand where the lag is coming from.  I wrapped the `set` in a `reltime`:

```
let a = reltime()
noautocmd set cpo-=c
let g:foo = reltimestr(reltime(a))
```

I inspect `g:foo` and it's 0.000025; much, much too low to be causing any sort of lag.  In fact, my entire `CursorMoved` autocommand takes no more than 10 milliseconds.  Replacing the `set` with a `sleep 10m` removes the "lag" entirely.

Another odd thing is the lag happens when using vim over SSH, but not locally.  So, why does `set cpo-=c` appear slow, but is not actually empirically slow?

Comment: In theory you can use `:verbose` and `'verbosefile'` to see if anything odd is happening. I would recommend using [`:Verbose`](https://github.com/tpope/vim-scriptease). However as you seem to get it when you ssh, I imagine this is some kind of terminal issue. If that is the case then you may want to make a minimal reproducible test case and submit a bug report (See `:h bug-reports`).

Comment: Didn't see anything strange with verbose.. it's a difficult-to-reproduce problem because it seems to depend on the terminal and/or connection speed (with slower connections being drastically worse).  Is this setting somehow incurring a round-trip communication?